# Detect change of select list using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

Is there a way to detect when the value of a select list is set to empty by a javasscript and *not* by the user? It seems that the change-event only triggers by mouse or keyboard.

And is there a way to detect when the number of options in a select list changes (added, removed)?

Comment: very similar to question 4967454

Answer (score 17):

You have to trigger the change event manually, when you are changing the value of a select with javascript. E.g:

```
$('#myselect').val(10).change();
```

In this example the value is set to 10 and the change event is triggered. If there is an event handler attached to the select, it will be executed.

Comment: This is seems to be the best answer, if a little non intutive. Strange  that it doesn't get trigger internally.

Answer (score 8):

> Use Jquery's [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function

`$("#idofselect").change(function(){ });`

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, not it's not possible to detect what caused the change in the select list in the change event itself.

However, if there is javascript code changing the select list you could add some logic in there to perform the tasks needed in this scenario.